# Top N in Cross Tab base on Column

Tags: crystal-reports

I have using Cross Tab in my report. The column is the Activities. The rows is the user name. The row will show the number of time the user attend those activities. How i can create a top N to show which activities has the most attendance? Please help. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you trying to restrict the Cross-Tab to the Top N activities, or are you just trying to find the Top N activities in general for display elsewhere in the report?

Comment: Hi Ryan, I wish to display in the report the Top N activities in the report.  Eg Activities is Swimming, Cycling and Football.  User A attend Swimming 10, Cycling 2 and Football 1. User B attend Swimming 3, Cycling 5 and Football 1.  I want to display in the crosstab the top 2 of most number of attendent which is Swimming and Cycling.  Football will not show in the record.  Can it be do that?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leave the Cross-Tab you have alone, then my suggestion would be to just add another Cross-Tab to the same report section that only has every activity summarized by row as counts of attendees. You could then restrict that CT to only show the Top-2 activities (By going to Group Sort Expert -> Sort by Top N -> N=2). You could even suppress the fields you don't want to show and hide the grid lines so that only the top 2 activities are actually spelled out.

An alternative is to pivot your original CT so that each row was an activity instead of a user, and then sort by the attendance in descending order. This would make it obvious which activities were the top 2.